# Using .net rx in regular REST API - does it make sense?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, system.reactive

I recently heard about reactive programming and started to explore Observer C# pattern and rx library. Despite some tutorials, articles and example use cases I still can't think if there are any benefits for my current project. It's pretty straightforward .net 6.0 web api. Controller with async methods returning `Task<IActionResult>`. Each method invokes and awaits for repository method that retrieves/modifies sql database data using Dapper. Is there any point in using rx library and implementing observer pattern instead if my API is a typical REST API with CRUD operations or would that be unneccessary overkill?

Comment: _"Is there any point in using rx library and implementing observer pattern instead if my API is a typical REST API with CRUD operations or would that be unneccessary overkill?"_ - Nope.

Comment: Do you have a stream of events? That's what Rx is for, not asynchronous programming. The question describes a CRUD scenario, not event processing. That's so generic *every* service, even event streaming ones, could be described as CRUD if they save any data

Comment: If your service did fraud detection based on repeated payments by the same card, Rx would help by aggregating payments by card over a specific window and returning those that exceeded a threshold. Your API would use CRUD, but that wouldn't be its main focus. If you used gRPC or SignalR you'd even have an actual event stream to process

Comment: Rx is extremely good when you have streams of values you're dealing receiving asynchronously - like lines read from file, or clicks from a user, or results from a task, timers firing. It effectively allows you to perform complex logic on those streams and joins of those streams. It makes your event handling far more concise and manageable. I avoid regular events, timers, etc, and use Rx for all of those things.